# how to update my network adapter?

Tags: network-interface, zorin

I have a TP LINK (TG-3468) connected to one port.  Whenever I format my computer and install Windows, I must update the adapter with the given CD.  How can I update the adapter in Zorin OS?

Comment: You don't need to. The problem with Windows is that you had to install the drivers again (not "updating" the adapter, which actually uses a firmware and without a good reason you shouldn't touch it) but if it worked with Linux once it should work again.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to boot Zorin with the TG-3468 installed and see what happens. My guess (after a little googling) is that it will work out of the box.

Once you've booted Zorin, open `xterm` and do `lspci`. See if you can find the ethernet card in that output. Do `ifconfig -a` and if you see a device named `eth`-something, TP LINK (TG-3468) will be working.